# Converting a non-standard datetime field in SQL server

Tags: sql-server-2008, datetime

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2. I've been given data that includes numerous varchar fields in the format mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss.mmmmmm AM. Here are some examples:

```
1/16/2013 10:31:38.000000 AM
11/12/2013 3:42:12.000000 PM
12/6/2013 2:42:46.000000 PM
```

I'd like to convert into a datetime format so I can work with them, but am having problems... I've found various sites that list the different date time formats (such as [this one](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/576178/cast-convert-format-try-parse-date-and-time-sql)), but this format isn't listed anywhere.

I've tried casting and converting in various different ways, including:

```
select CAST (field as datetime) from table;

select CONVERT (datetime, field, 101)
from table;
```

But I keep getting this error: 
`"Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."`

I presume because the format my field is in isn't standard so SQL can't recognize it?

Any help would be appreciated. Apologies if this has been covered before - I've spent 4 hours searching this and other sites but can't find the answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't you be casting to Datetime2 type instead? The Datetime has precision only as high as to milliseconds.